# Assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key category but you have no mapping for it

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Note really sure what to do. I'm trying to use a slug instead of ID but when I try to go directly to a link (/categories/source), I get the error. I've tried adding mappings in the RESTadapter but it hasn't worked. I ha

I've a feeling that my problem is in my CategoryRoute/model code but I can't see to get the right combo. Any help is appreciated.

To be honest, I don't know why it has to make two REST calls when it's already got the model info available. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Json responses

```
{"categories":[{"id":1,"name":"Misc","slug":"misc"},{"id":2,"name":"Technology","slug":"technology"},{"id":3,"name":"Ecommerce","slug":"ecommerce"},{"id":4,"name":"Visitor","slug":"visitor"},{"id":5,"name":"Content","slug":"content"},{"id":6,"name":"evars","slug":"evars"},{"id":7,"name":"Marketing","slug":"marketing"},{"id":8,"name":"Props","slug":"props"},{"id":9,"name":"Source","slug":"source"}]}

{"category":{"id":2,"name":"Technology","slug":"technology"}}
```

Html file

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LayerSpark</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>{{#linkTo 'categories'}}Categories{{/linkTo}}</li>
                <li>{{#linkTo 'help'}}Help{{/linkTo}}</li>
                <li>{{#linkTo 'account'}}Account{{/linkTo}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
                {{outlet}}

    </div>

</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="categories">

    <div  {{bindAttr class=":row"}}>
        <div {{bindAttr class=":col-lg-4"}}>
            <ul>
                {{#each model}}
                <li>{{#linkTo 'category' this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div {{bindAttr class=":col-lg-8"}}>
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="category">
   Post:<br>
    My name is :: {{ name }}<br>
    My id is :: {{id}}<br>
    My slug is :: {{slug}}<br>

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="categories/index">
    <p class="text-warning">Please select a Category</p>
</script>
```

App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS:true
});
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr('string'),
    slug: attr('string')
});

DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
    category: "categories"
});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        url: '/api',
        mappings:{
            category:'App.Category'
        }
    })
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('about');
    this.resource('categories', function() {
        this.resource('category',{path:':category_slug'});
    });
    this.resource('help');
    this.resource('account');
});

App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return App.Category.find();
    }
});

App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(route,model) {
        console.log(route);window.mod = model;
        return App.Category.find({slug:route.category_slug});
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return {
            category_slug: model.get('slug')
        };
    }
});


Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('markdown', function(input) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(input));
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('date', function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
});
```

Comment: What routes/URLs are you trying to create? I think the error means that ember does not know what /category maps to in the router.

Comment: I was trying to link to /categories/{slug}

Answer (score 0):

I used the following router setup so that I could have a resource of Post corresponding to a route of /posts/:id. Also gives comments belonging to posts.

```
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('comments', function() {
      this.route('new');
      this.route('create');
    });
    this.route('comment', { path: 'comments/:comment_id'});
  });
```

I had to define the categories resource separately and then explicitly state that post was under the /posts route in the definition of the resource. Maybe you need a router like:

```
this.resource('categories', function() {});
this.resource('category',{path:'/categories/:category_slug'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't have readily available to test but I'll see if I can check out an old commit and test it. It was the only thing keeping from using Ember. I've since started using React.js but I'd love to see if this solved my mystery, thanks again!